# Python: Insert multiple values into new columns at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data frame looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+-----------+
| val1 | val2 | val3 |   col1    |
+------+------+------+-----------+
|    3 |    1 |    1 | something | 
|    4 |    2 |    1 | sth else  |
|    2 |    2 |    3 | something | 
|    3 |    1 |    1 | sth else  |
|    2 |    2 |    1 | something | 
+------+------+------+-----------+
```

I want to insert values into 3 different columns if they meet a condition (mask).

For the first 2 columns it works, so inserting usual strings is fine. How do I insert the product of multiple values from other columns of the same row.

So this does work for `Issue` and `Type` but `Value` does not work:

```
mask = (df.col1 == 'something')
df[['Issue','Type','Value']] = np.where( mask[:, None], ['sth','One', str(np.prod(df.iloc[:, 0:3], axis=1))], ['','',''])
```

In this case I want to insert the multiplication of `val1`, `val2` and `val3` within the same row as string into `Value`.

Desired output:

```
+------+------+------+-----------+-------+------+-------+
| val1 | val2 | val3 |   col1    | Issue | Type | Value |
+------+------+------+-----------+-------+------+-------+
|    3 |    1 |    1 | something | sth   | One  |     3 |
|    4 |    2 |    1 | sth else  |       |      |       |
|    2 |    2 |    3 | something | sth   | One  |    12 |
|    3 |    1 |    1 | sth else  |       |      |       |
|    2 |    2 |    1 | something | sth   | One  |     4 |
+------+------+------+-----------+-------+------+-------+
```

PS.: Sorry about the headline, difficult to describe shortly.

Comment: Can you share example of input? You just need that for [mcve]

Comment: thought the output would explain enough, sorry. Added input

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `assign` and `combine_first`

```
df.combine_first(df.assign(**dict(zip(['Issue','Type','Value'],['sth','One', np.prod(df.iloc[:, 0:3], axis=1).values]))).loc[mask,:])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply using the pandas .loc indexer function:

```
mask = (df.col1 == 'something')

df.loc[mask,'Issue']='sth'
df.loc[mask,'Type']='One'
df.loc[mask,'Value']=df.loc[mask,'val1']*df.loc[mask,'val2']*df.loc[mask,'val3']
```

Answer (score 0):

This would require multiple `assign`s but it does the job:

```
values = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
results = df.val1 * df.val2 * df.val3

df = df.assign(Issue=np.where(mask, 'sth', '')).assign(Type=np.where(mask, 'sth', '')).assign(Value=np.where(mask, results, ''))
```

`Value` will be `str` automatically due to value of other argument in `np.where`.

Answer (score 0):

This requires the reindexing, and might not be efficiënt for big sets, but should do the job!

```
df = df.reindex(columns = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'col1', 'Issue','Type','Value'])
df['Issue'], df['Type'], df['Value'] = zip(*df[['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'col1']].apply(lambda x: ('sth', 'One' , str(np.prod(x[:3])) ) if x[3] == 'something' else (None,None,None), axis = 1))
```